# Best practice for passing arguments to an event handler function

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

Suppose I have a button (several buttons actually) that when clicked will do 1 of 2 things. Which of those 2 things depends on an argument passed to the function. This will be used all over so I need to put in a function... as opposed to having the code execute in an anonymous function each time. I'm using jquery and wondering what the best way is to feed the click-handler function a parameter and value. Also, I'd like to keep a reference to the button intact as `$(this)` if at all possible. here's what i've got:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#button1').click({ labelStr: 'Open File' }, doLabel);
   $('#button2').click({ labelStr: 'Close Window' }, doLabel);
});

function doLabel(e) {
  console.log('it is: %o', e.data.labelStr);
  $(this).html(e.data.labelStr);
}
```

...which works - [jsfiddel](https://jsfiddle.net/daveh0/fsjcrphu/1/) - but I know there are many ways to skin this cat. What holes can be poked in this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me.  Are you looking for a way to pass arguments and have them map directly to the click handler's parameters list?  If that's the case, you can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#button1').click(function() {doLabel.call(this, "Open File");});
   $('#button2').click(function() {doLabel.call(this, "Close Window");});
});

function doLabel(labelStr) {
  console.log('it is: %o', labelStr);
  $(this).html(labelStr);
}
```

If there are multiple parameters, you can do `doLabel.call(this, arg1, arg2, ...)`.

Comment: This looks pretty close to what I was going for. I don't see this that often. Is it better practice to write event handlers that don't require arguments?

Comment: I don't know if it's necessarily better practice, but it is definitely easier, since you can just pass the function name instead of having to wrap it in an anonymous function (and, as you want to avoid, lose the `this` reference).

Answer (score 1):

Like DelightedD0D suggested, I would also use data attributes. You can use $(this) in your event handler to reference the element, and so avoid the anonymous functions.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('button').click(doLabel);
});

function doLabel() {
  $(this).html($(this).data('label-str'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-label-str="Open File">Give me a label please</button>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<button data-label-str="Close Window">Give ME a label TOO please</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I'd just add the string as a data attribute on the button and send `this` to the function. Let the function use `this` to get the string from the button

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/fsjcrphu/3/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('button').click(function(){doLabel(this)});
});

function doLabel(e) {
  $(e).html($(e).data('label-str'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-label-str="Open File">Give me a label please</button>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<button data-label-str="Close Window">Give ME a label TOO please</button>
```

Comment: I guess I was trying to avoid having to wrap the click-handler function in another anonymous function...  but I'm not sure why... extra overhead? more code?

Comment: @Daveh0I cant think of any situation where this would cause any sort of performance issues. IMHO, this method is more typical.